# Where does the name "Yiga" come from?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom, legend-of-zelda-series

I've been told that the Sheikah race in the *Legend of Zelda* series were originally named the "Seekers"; when adapted to Japanese phonology that becomes *Shiikaa* which was transcribed back into English as "Sheikah". (The same happened with some other names in Ocarina of Time: the desert people were named after the "Geld Man" desert enemy in A Link to the Past, and "Geld" became *Gerudo* and thus "Gerudo".)

Since the Yiga are an offshoot of the Sheikah, I'd expect their name to be related. But it doesn't sound like any English word I know. ("Eager" maybe? But it's a stretch.)

Do we know where the name "Yiga" came from? Is it also adapted from English, or is it originally Japanese, or something else?

Comment: The "Geld" transliteration of the Japanese  ゲルド dates back to at least [Adventure of Link](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Geldarm), not just A Link to the Past.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is originally Japanese.

Additionally, their master's name, Kohga, also came from Japanese.

Both names came from the Ninja school/clans [Iga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iga-ry%C5%AB) and [Kōga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dga-ry%C5%AB), the most well-known Ninja school/clans in Japan.

There is no doubt that the Yiga Clan is based on Ninjas, given its characteristics, and that Japanese fan sites also refer to it as such, and of course the names Yiga and Kohga, but it is not 100% certain. I'd say 99% certain, though.